# there seems to be a statement that is provable in integrable system, please let me know where can I learn about this statement.

Tags: integrable-systems

the statement is:

given $f,g \in C^{\infty}(M)$ the it's true that   $\xi_{\{f,g\}}=[\xi_{f},\xi_{g}]$

M should be a symplectic poisson manifold

Comment: You might want to give a little more info. so people understand what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm at the lecture now, the lecturer even doesn't know. not that it is too complicated the lecturer dosen't know what he is doing. typical of classes in russia actually

Comment: Is $\{f,g\}$ the Poisson bracket, while $[\xi_{f},\xi_{g}]$ is the Lie bracket?

Comment: @PaulSinclair sounds like it is